# How to send pickle file to FastAPI call as input?

Tags: python, pickle, fastapi

My attempt:

Client:

```
import requests
input_file = open(r'test_file.pkl', 'rb')
files = {'input_file': input_file}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/forecast', files=files)
```

API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/forecast')
def forecast(input_file: bytes = File()):
    data = pickle.loads(input_file)
    return {'data':len(data)}
```

I am getting `EOFError: Ran out of input`.
I suspect it is because I am sending file in a wrong way, but I don't know how else I can send the .pkl file to FastAPI.

Comment: I would heavily advise against doing this. [Pickle is  an insecure format](https://medium.com/ochrona/python-pickle-is-notoriously-insecure-d6651f1974c9) and can let anyone run arbitrary code on your server. If at all within the realm of possibility, try to serialize your input as JSON instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and a good advice, I didn't know it is insecure. I chose it instead of JSON to keep the data formatting but I suppose in this case it is better to go with JSON and change formats within API.